# Redirection issues in Live server

Tags: .htaccess

My .htaccess is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ index.php/page/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|asset|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

But it's not working in mochahost I tried several time but it's not working. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: What version are you using of codeigniter and are you using xampp or wamp?

Comment: Is mod_rewrite activated on you live server

Comment: how is this related to mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This Code in .htaccess works for me........

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```