# This page isn’t working HTTP ERROR 500 on codeigniter 3, but work perfectly on localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, apache2

when i visit my web url it shows like this [my online site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJNv6.png)

[image]

but it work perfectly when i run my web on localhost

maybe it cause .htaccess
here it is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*)\.xml(.*) $1.php?$2 [nocase]
```

i put this .htaccess code at 
[this is my site when online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZUGU.png)
[image]

Comment: Are you use windows os on your live web server ?

Comment: are you placed your live site in any subfolder like, www.example.com/demo

Comment: try this [htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364031/redirection-issues-in-live-server/43364089#43364089)

Comment: @YadhuBabu no, i put my files on root without sub folder

Comment: @GopalBhuva not working, any other solution ?

Comment: This is first time I see someone tries  `nocase` for flag. Try with `NC` instead.

Comment: this url is working.. [your site](http://115.85.64.66/)

Comment: @Tpojka u mean code for htaccess file ? please write ur htaccess file here bro

Comment: Try with this line changed this way: `RewriteRule (.*)\.xml(.*) $1.php?$2 [NC]`.

Comment: Try checking the permission on the PHP files. Sometimes it may cause 500 error

Comment: @Tpojka not working bro

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
set $config['base_url'] = '';
```