# Codeigniter project is not working after installing at server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, .htaccess, codeigniter

I build codeigniter project and i have tested it in my local machine using http://localhost/wg/ as base url. I upload that project to server and my new url like http://project.microsols.com/wardrobe/ Home page is working. But when i click on any other link it will give error.
It is giving

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /index.php/person was not found on this server.
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

But it will work fine when i put index.php before my controller it will work fine..
And this is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /wardrobe/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

What is the issue behind this error??

Comment: try this `.htaccess` it's working on most of the server [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364031/redirection-issues-in-live-server/43364089#43364089)

Comment: It works (Y) thank  :)

Answer (score 0):

Paste this code in your .htaccess file and then try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

By default codeigniter urls include the index.php in the url. You need to remove index.php from the url to make it work. Please follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url) to do the same.