# how to do Ajax on Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I am just trying to do simple ajax on my codeigniter website.

Here is the my view code and is there some way to debug from controller?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 text-left">Nama Lengkap
        <span class="text-danger">*</span>
    </label>

    <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="" name="nama_lengkap" id="nama_lengkap" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript

```
$('#nama_lengkap').change(function(){
    var nama_lengkap = $('#nama_lengkap').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('formulir/update_data'); ?>", 
        data:nama_lengkap,
        dataType:"json",//return type expected as json
        success: function(states){
                     console.log("sukses update" + states);
        },
    });
});
```

Here is my controller formulir.php

```
public function update_data(){
    $nama_lengkap = $_POST["nama_lengkap"];
    return $nama_lengkap;
}
```

Comment: what is the error what is the output ?

Comment: my bad.

http://localhost/PSB-IPH/index.php/formulir/update_data 404 (Not Found)'.

i have trouble with url: "<?php echo site_url('formulir/update_data'); ?>"

Comment: You want the request to be fired from `localhost/PSB-IPH/index.php/formulir/update_data` are you sure ?

Comment: Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364031/redirection-issues-in-live-server/43364089#43364089) `.htaccess` and also change `url: "<?php echo base_url()?>formulir/update_data"`

Comment: Punctuation and code indentation.

Comment: @GopalBhuva brings up a good point. You should try and include a .htaccess file to remove the 'index.php' part of the URL. have you tried to access the URL 'localhost/PSB-IPH/index.php/formulir/update_data' by typing it into the URL bar and seeing what it resolves to? If you get a 404 by doing that, check that your URL is being spelled correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On header create a javascript varaible.

```
<script>var BASE_URL = <?php echo base_url(); ?></script>
```

now you dont have to use php code every where in ajax code. Just use

```
url: BASE_URL+'controller/function',
data:{'nama_lengkap':nama_lengkap},
```

and now in controller used the proper codeigniter input type syntax like this:

```
$nama_lengkap = $this->input->post('nama_lengkap');
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you need to adjust this line in your javascript ajax:

```
data:{nama_lengkap: nama_lengkap}
```