# CodeIgniter server tests give 404?

Tags: php, codeigniter

A client askmed me to write RESTful API using CodeIgniter. Maybe [codeigniter-restserver](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver) can make my task easier. So I downloaded the package, extract it, and upload it to both servers: my development server (123.100.77.10/ci-server), and the production server (99.40.143.100/ci-server). The only difference is the **$config['base_url']** value (in *application/config/config.php*)

I had no problem running the tests on my development server. All test cases passed succesfully. But on the production server, each of them gives 404.

Anyone ever encountered this issue? How to solve this?

[image]

Comment: have you put [.htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43364031/redirection-issues-in-live-server/43364089#43364089) file?

Comment: @GopalBhuva in which directory?

Comment: in your root folder .. and also check that [Class Naming Rules](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html)

Comment: @GopalBhuva No, I don't use any .htaccess file. And not sure about the Class Naming Rules, because I don't write any code here. It's straight from [codeigniter-server](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver). If you can run the tests on your server, let me know :)